# inner join display list of sales by customer

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to Display a list of sales by customer, showing customer ID, the customer’s name, the
name of the product bought by the customer, and the date of sale and be  sorted by the customer id..

here is the  customer table structure

```
CREATE TABLE customer 
(cust_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,forename CHAR(10) NOT NULL
,surname CHAR(10) NOT NULL
,phone CHAR(15) NULL
);
```

here is the sales table structure

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(cust_id CHAR(6) NOT NULL
,prod_id CHAR(8) NOT NULL
,quantity SMALLINT NULL 
,date_of_sale NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(cust_id,prod_id)
);
```

thank you.

products table

[image]

Comment: You have to be consistent with your data types. If a PK column is INT then the Foreign Key that references should also be INT. Also, people have names of different length (and often more than 10 characters), so VARCHAR() would be a better choice. Finally, it's possible for a user to buy a product of NULL quantity, on a NULL date. This is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you a list of your customers, it uses LEFT JOINS - which means the results will show you customers that have no sales as well as customers with sales - which is probably information you want to know.

```
SELECT 
c.cust_id, 
c.forename, 
c.surname, 
p.prod_name, 
s.date_of_sale
FROM customers c 
LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.cust_id = c.cust_id
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.prod_id = s.prod_id 
ORDER BY c.cust_id ASC
```

If you only want to see customers that have sales - then just change `LEFT` to `INNER`.

```
SELECT 
c.cust_id, 
c.forename, 
c.surname, 
p.prod_name, 
s.date_of_sale
FROM customers c 
INNER JOIN sales s ON s.cust_id = c.cust_id
INNER JOIN products p ON p.prod_id = s.prod_id 
ORDER BY c.cust_id ASC
```

Comment: I need  a list of  sales by  customers

Comment: @Jmac88 the query shows you customers with sales as well as customers without sales.

Comment: I get the following error:
#1146 - Table 'computer_wholesale.customer' doesn't exist

Comment: jmac why do you keep talking about that ridiculous table name. do you know what you are highlighting and executing or did you fall into a software job today

Comment: is the table called customers?

Comment: @drewpierce no i'm  just  working on something for myself.i think i am getting that error because its customers table not 'customer'....

Comment: @Donal also its products not product

Comment: your queries are becoming quite similar jmac. best to start pounding them out yourself

Comment: ok sorry drew 

@Donal that query just displays  this http://gyazo.com/b9eb6e46023b034df43aed898d8ed6ef

Comment: @Jmac88 change the left to inner.

Comment: @Jmac88 inner join - this will only return customers that have sales - assuming the data is there.

Comment: @Jmac88 see the second query in my answer.